# Stop mobile Safari from preloading HTML5 audio

Tags: iphone, ios, html, html5-audio

I am trying to get mobile Safari on and iPhone 5 to stop preloading a HTML5 audio element. I can see in the server log that it is still calling the MP3 file even though I have `preload` set to `none`. Any ideas on how to get it to stop or a way around this? I'm trying to keep a log in a MySQL database, but with it doing this, it is throwing things off.

**EDIT**

If you try the following code and then check the server log, you'll see the audio was still called.
`<audio  preload="none" id="audio" src="mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>`

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:

> Note: The preload attribute is supported in Safari 5.0 and later. Safari on iOS never preloads.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW9

Comment: Then why does the file get called?

Comment: if you try <audio preload="none" id="audio" src="mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio> and then check the server log you'll see it called the audio file.

Comment: Try removing the `preload` attribute altogether. Can you see the request type in your server logs? Is it a GET or HEAD request?